# php web page password empty validation

Tags: javascript, php, web

I wanted to check if the username and password fields are empty. 
If they are empty it should give a error message box and the message box should contain a message and a ok button.
When user clicks the ok button the msg box should close and user should see the login page.

For that i wrote the below code. but after pressing the ok button on error message box the web page address is remaining same but the content is not getting displayed , full white page is displayed.

you do refresh and page comes back.

This is the file i am opening in browser register.php

```
<?php

// configuration
require("../includes/config.php");

// if user reached page via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET")
{
    // else render form
    render("register_form.php", ["title" => "Register"]);
}

// else if user reached page via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
else if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    // TODO
    if (empty($_POST["username"]) || empty($_POST["password"]))
    {
        $message = "Username and/or Password empty.\\nTry again.";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    }   
}
?>
```

And this is the form file register_form.php

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username :</label>
        <input autofocus class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
         <label>Password :</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
         <label>Password :</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="confirmation" placeholder="Retype-Password" type="password"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

i want to see login page after clicking the ok button on the message box i do not want to see white page. please help

Comment: Can you post full code please?

Comment: agree with Zak, we would need to see more of your code - both PHP and HTML

Comment: @Zak pasted the full code

Comment: @ZathrusWriter pasted the full code

Comment: Put the PHP code in the same file as the form HTML (remember the change the form `action`).

Comment: @Zak here is the full link to the full code   i just added the check for empty string after creating the register_form.php from login.php   [link] (http://cdn.cs50.net/2014/fall/psets/7/pset7/pset7.zip) (Actually i am beginner in web programming and i was doing CS50 online)

Comment: @luck Sorry, can't see the link...

Comment: @Zak mistakenly pressed the enter while i was writing the link.

Comment: @Zak i found that there is a function apologize that i can use that opens a different page show error and after pressing back it again comes back to register.php.  By using the concept i hope i can use render function  after printing the display . But i dont know how to call the render function exactly after user clicks on the error javascript message box.

Comment: Put `render("register_form.php")` also after `echo` with your error maybe?